# Two dynamic class added on same element at same time

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap website I added **fullpage.js**, so when a dynamically one class want to add to the page. But two dynamic class added on same element at same time.
So it changed the functionality.

One class only add to the element. 
I tried but didn't worked.
Can you please help me to solve this problem.

This is my code, in this code(**fp-tableCell**) class added two times

```
<section class="icon-section fp-section fp-table active" id="section-1">
<div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:600px;">
<div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:600px;">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                      <img src="images/product-1.png" alt="img" class="max-width">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 banner-txt">
                      <h3 class="preHeading"">volant</h3>
                      <h1 class="mainHeading">an icon for iconoclasts</h1>
                      <p class="description">Our singular purpose was to create a product not<br>
                         bound by convention. 
                        Volant is the realization of that<br> dream.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Add your code please what you tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your responce, i added my code. can you please help me.

Comment: Can we see the code that is adding the elements?

Comment: yeah..but i can't add here..it's too long code.

Comment: I am just interested in the specific part that actually inserts the elements or adds the classes. But you can post to something like [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Thanks @JustinT. I pasted on this url-  https://pastebin.com/PYTKxySc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that generates the two `<div>` elements appears to have been [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and is therefore very difficult to interpret. I think the easiest way to solve this problem would be to remove the duplicate `<div>` elements from all of the `<section>` elements after the document has loaded. To do this, you can insert the following code just before your closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
var sectionElems = document.getElementsByTagName("section"); //creates an array containing all <section> elements
var outerDiv;
var innerDiv;

//loop through each <section> element found and remove duplicate <div> element
for(var i = 0; i < sectionElems.length; i++){
    outerDiv = sectionElems[i].children[0];
    innerDiv = outerDiv.children[0];
    //check class names to make sure it is a duplicate element
    if(outerDiv.className == innerDiv.className){
        outerDiv.innerHTML = innerDiv.innerHTML;
    }
}
</script>
```

This code loops through each `<section>` element and writes the content of the nested `<div>` element into the parent `<div>` element, basically overwriting itself without including the nested `<div>` element.

Comment: I can able to saw the alert message, but that problem cant't be  fixed..again the class add two times .@justin.T

Comment: Sorry you're still having trouble with this. Would you mind posting the URL of the live site?

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue now. When I run it, I get the message and see that it has been successfully removed from the first `<section>`, but not the others. Since you only posted the `<section>` with `id='section-1'`, I thought that was the only one that had the issue. I will update my solution shortly...

Comment: I have updated my solution, this is working well on my end. Remember to paste the code just before your closing `</body>` tag at the bottom of your HTML document.

Comment: yeah...its's working now...thank you so much for your help...@Justin T.

Comment: Yeah! In my website i used barba.js, That's why your script not worked..again i removed barba, Then i insert your script now It's fine.....Thanks buddy.